# system not showing full capacity of SSD drives

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

i have 3 SSD disks on my server (500GB, 1.2TB, 1.2TB)

but `df -h` doesn't show full capacity of my system

```
user@hostname:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            252G     0  252G   0% /dev
tmpfs            51G  9.4M   51G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       440G  1.8G  416G   1% /
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1000
```

even thought when running `lsblk` i can see all my drives

```
user@hostname:~$ lsblk 
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1                   8:1    0 446.2G  0 part /
├─sda2                   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                   8:5    0   976M  0 part [SWAP]
nvme0n1                259:1    0   1.1T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1            259:2    0   1.1T  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2            259:5    0     1K  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5            259:6    0   976M  0 part 
nvme1n1                259:0    0   1.1T  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1            259:3    0   731M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p2            259:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p5            259:7    0   1.1T  0 part 
  ├─aspera2--vg-root   252:0    0   1.1T  0 lvm  
  └─aspera2--vg-swap_1 252:1    0   976M  0 lvm
```

when trying to create a partition on the on of the nvme disks i get the following error

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/nvme0n1

Command (m for help): n
All space for primary partitions is in use.
Adding logical partition 6
No free sectors available.
```

Any help is appreciated
thank you.

Comment: Your LVM install always uses the full drive. You then have to use LVM tools to add logical volumes inside the LVM. Standard partition tools do not work with LVM. Advantages/Disadvantages LVM Post #9
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586328&p=9917145#post9917145
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM & 
https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lsblk command is showing you the disks and the partitions on the disks.  It is also showing you if the partition is mounted or not.

The df command is displaying the filesystems that are currently mounted.

It does not appear all partitions are mounted.  The lsblk output shows only /dev/sda1 is mounted, at /.  /dev/sda2, /dev/sda5, /dev/nvme0n1p1, /dev/nvme0n1p2, /dev/nvme0n1p5, /dev/nvme1n1p1, /dev/nvme1n1p2 and /dev/nvme1n1p5 are not mounted.  Furthermore, the lsblk output shows that /dev/nvme1n1p5 is a LVM physical volume with 2 logical volumes on it.  So, there are some filesystems associated with that partition, but they are not mounted.

If you are ok with those partitions, and they do not have any filesystems on them, you can make a filesystem on one of the partitions and then mount it.

If you are not ok with those partitions, you can remove the existing partitions and create new ones.  You can then make filesystems on those new partitions and then mount them.

Hope this helps.